# Calling Scipy's RectBivariateSpline evaluation function in Cython using openmp

Tags: scipy, openmp, cython

I would really like to run the `scipy.interpolation.RectBivariateSpline.ev` function using Cython with openmp. The evaluation function for the spline is now the last remaining bottleneck in my code to be optimized.

As a stopgap, I am using Python's `multiprocessing` package to make the evaluation of large arrays of coordinates bearable... but, for several reasons, we need to move away from the `multiprocessing` package.

My last stop before refactoring the Fortran `bisplev` function into C and then wrapping with Cython is to try to wrap the Scipy `scipy.interpolate._fitpack._bisplev` function with openmp and Cython.

As I expected (but hoped would not be the case), `_bisplev` is a Python object and not `cdef`d and cannot be called with `nogil` in Cython. I have looked but cannot find the source of `_bisplev`, but I now imagine it is some kind of Fortran-C-Python interface. (That's a wishy washy statement on my part because I have no clue exactly what it is).

If anybody has any suggestions on where I can go from here... specifically the best way to parallelize the `scipy.interpolation.RectBivariateSpline.ev` call without using Python `multiprocessing`, I would be most grateful. Any other tips or nudges in the right direction would also be greatly appreciated.

My first stab at making (naive) Cython wrapper for `bispev` with the intent to parallelize with openmp::

**interp2_fastev.pyx**

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate._fitpack import _bispev

def ev(double[:] x, double[:] y, double[:] ty, int kx, int ky, double[:] tx, double[:] c):
    cdef int ckx
    cdef int cky
    ckx = kx
    cky = ky   

    with nogil:
        _bispev(tx, ty, c, kx, ky, x, y, 0, 0)
```

I intend to eventually use a `prange` loop, but that's not an option if I can't even call `_bispev` with `nogil`.

Answer (score 2):

`_fitpack` is a compiled file (.so): `/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack.cpython-35m-i386-linux-gnu.so`

Searching on `github` I find

```
scipy/scipy/interpolate/src/_fitpackmodule.c
scipy/scipy/interpolate/src/__fitpack.h
```

The 2nd has the definition of

```
static char doc_bispev[] = " [z,ier] = _bispev(tx,ty,c,kx,ky,x,y,nux,nuy)";
fitpack_bispev(PyObject *dummy, PyObject *args)
```

which appears to take care of memory allocations and calls Fortran:

```
BISPEV(tx, &nx, ty, &ny, c, &kx, &ky, x, &mx, y, &my, z, wrk, &lwrk,
            iwrk, &kwrk, &ier);
```

with fortran code in:

```
scipy/scipy/interpolate/src/fitpack.pyf
```

Comment: There are really two separate extensions, `_fitpack` and `dftitpack`. `fitpackmodule.c` and `__fitpack.h` are for the first one, and `dftipack` is created from the `pyf` wrapper https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/setup.py#L25

Comment: `bispev` seems to come from `dfitpack`, so `__fitpack.h` and `fitpackmodule.c` are irrelevant for this specific question. (yes, it's a mess)

Comment: Moreover, to release the GIL, you likely need a recent enough scipy: the pyf wrappers were only marked as threadsafe for scipy 0.17 IIRC.

Comment: @ev-br Thank u for the suggestion and insight! Unfortunately I am tied to a lower version at the moment.. but I will revisit this when we do an upgrade to Py3.5. It boggles the mind that there doesnt appear to be a good parallelized alternative for interpolation  :(

Comment: Thanks for tracking this down @hpaulj. It doesnt give me everything i need but between ur response and the comment i have more than i did.

Answer (score 1):

After some experiments, I ended up with the following solution: I added a few OpenMP directives and created two additional thread-local variables in the fortran routine **bispeu.f** and modified **scipy/interpolate**'s build script to call fortran compiler with OpenMP support.

Relevant lines in **scipy/interpolate/fitpack/bispeu.f** with added OpenMP-related code:

```
      subroutine bispeu(tx,nx,ty,ny,c,kx,ky,x,y,z,m,wrk,lwrk, ier)
c  ......................
c  (comments)
c  ......................
      include 'omp_lib.h'
      integer nx,ny,kx,ky,m,lwrk,ier
c  ..array arguments..
      real*8 tx(nx),ty(ny),c((nx-kx-1)*(ny-ky-1)),x(m),y(m),z(m),
     *     wrk(lwrk)
c  ..local scalars..
      integer iwrk(2)
      integer i, lwest
c  ..thread-private buffers
      real*8 wrk_local(lwrk)
      integer iwrk_local(2)
c...................
c (unchanged lines)
c...................

c$omp parallel do private(wrk_local,iwrk_local)
      do 10 i=1,m
         call fpbisp(tx,nx,ty,ny,c,kx,ky,x(i),1,y(i),1,z(i),
     *   wrk_local(1),wrk_local(kx+2),iwrk_local(1),iwrk_local(2))
 10   continue
c$omp end parallel do
```

Relevant lines in **scipy/interpolate/setup.py**

**before**

```py
    fitpack_src = [join('fitpack', '*.f')]
    config.add_library('fitpack', sources=fitpack_src,
                       _pre_build_hook=pre_build_hook)
```

and **after** modification

```py
    fitpack_src = [join('fitpack', '*.f')]
    config.add_library('fitpack', sources=fitpack_src,
                       _pre_build_hook=pre_build_hook,
                       extra_f77_compile_args=['-fopenmp'])
```

**Note** that I modified `bispeu()` routine instead of `bispev()`.
The former is more relevant in my case since it returns `z` of the same shape as input `x` and `y` and it is the routine used by `BivariateSpline.ev` actually.

Comparison of performance of serial and parallel `bispeu()` on 3x3 degree spline defined on 500x500 grid called on 10 million points on my MacBook Air (2020) with quad-core 1.1 GHz Intel Core i5 gives following timings:

- **Serial** version from scipy: **5.592 s**
- **Parallelized** version: **3.033 s**

---

Before arriving to this solution I tried to import compiled fortran routines into Cython (according to [this](https://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html#interfacing-with-c) guide) and use `prange()` or `parallel()` Cython functions. This required me to write an additional fortran wrapper to bind fortran subroutines to C. This also gave no performance gain compared to serial version.

Comment: Wow this is years later!! I'll have to back and get my headspace into this problem. Blast from the past!